# zend framework - php zftool/zf.php display home page html

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have installed zend framework on my local and it works fine from the browser url. Now i want to use zftool, so i have downloaded zftool and extracted on my project root directly by renaming it to zftool.
Now in windows command console i am redirected to my project root folder and try to execute zftool command. e.g "d:/xampp/htdocs/zend>php zftool/zf.php version". So instead of executing zftool command, it shows me the home page html in console.
Please help me where i am wrong in the process of using zftool.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're trying to use ZFtool with ZF3, and it just doesn't work.
https://github.com/zendframework/tutorials/issues/16

You can check your ZF version with `composer info`.